# Mysql_fetch_object Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a php blog from scratch.
Everything is working except the menu. I run this code on a different CMS and it is working, but on the blog I am building is not.

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="<?php echo DIR;?>">HOME</a></li>
<?php
    //get the rest of the pages
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE isRoot='1' ORDER BY pageID");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
    {
        echo "<li><a href=\"".DIR."?p=$row->pageID\">$row->pageTitle</a></li>"; 
    }
?>
```

I get the Home link but not the rest.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *not working* ? Did you get any errors ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How do you "run this code"? (You can edit your question to add precisions)

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: where is your database connection??

Answer (score -1):

First, and a minor note at that, you might want to look into your usage of quotation marks in the echo line. i.e.:

```
<?php echo "<li><a href=\"".DIR."?p=".$row->pageID."\">".$row->pageTitle."</a></li>"; ?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php echo "<li><a href=\"".DIR."?p=$row->pageID\">$row->pageTitle</a></li>"; ?>
```

I bring this up because I think this is where your issue lies. If you look into the source code, it would truly clarify whether this is truly the issue.

In regards to cross-CMS support, some CMS suites have different magicquotes usage and filtering schemes, which would explain you're confusion that way. In my personal opinion, I would assume that your inclusion of PHP within the echo statement without concatenation is the root of your issue. Post the PHP error or source code of the element in question (in Chrome, right click one the menu and select "Inspect element"). This will clear up any of the questions we have and enable us to help you further if my solution isn't correct.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it should be a comment.

Comment: I can't comment because my reputation is below 50, I apologize for this causing trouble.